# Isolate pods in a namepace from other namespaces using network policy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Is there a way to isolate one namespace from accessing other namespace but still be able to go outside the cluster
I have 10 namespaces, I want that pods within this 1 namespace are not be able to talk to other namespaces but still be able to go outside the cluster to external resources
while this is applied to only 1 namespace the other 9 namespaces can talk to each other

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default //your 1 namespaces on which you want to deny all traffic.
  name: deny-from-other-namespaces
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
  ingress:
 - from:
    - podSelector: {}
```

**Note a few things about this manifest:**

- namespace: default deploys it to the default namespace.Please change it as per your need.
- It applies the policy to ALL pods in default namespace as the
  spec.podSelector.matchLabels is empty and therefore selects all pods.
- It allows traffic from ALL pods in the default namespace, as
  spec.ingress.from.podSelector is empty and therefore selects all
  pods.
  Here is an awesome on network policy github [repo](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes) from which i have taken this example.